# Symfony3 Dynamic Connection with wrapper_class in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a central database of licenses by company in which I save the connection values to a specific database by company, I need to be able to consult the central database and readjust the parameters of connection to the dynamically specified database, without having to create in my config.yml all the connections.

I have a code that I found that allows you to overwrite the connection, but I do not know how to use it to change the connection.

```
//config.yml
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                wrapper_class: AppBundle\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8


//AppBundle\Doctrine\DynamicConnection.php
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

class DynamicConnection extends Connection
{
     public function __construct (array $ params, Driver $ driver, $ config, $ eventManager)
     {
         $ params ['dbname'] = 'database_central';
         parent :: __ construct ($ params, $ driver, $ config, $ eventManager);
     }
}
```